# How to get the ID number of MPU 9150

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope, i2c, arduino-uno, magnetometer

I am using MPU 9150 for the first time with Arduino and therefore your answers will be a great help.

I am using I2C communication protocol and in order start getting the raw data I want to know the ID number of MPU 9150 so that communication between arduino and MPU 9150 is made possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's either 0x68 or 0x69. Depending if you pulled the AD0 pin to GND or to VCC.